# Parsing multiple argument line with different types and saving them in variables

Tags: c

I am trying to parse multiple argument lines like this:

```
./practice x 33

./practice y 42
```

where the x and y specify which array (either the one containing x or y coordinates) im searching in and which number im looking for in that array. How do I parse these in my program and store their values in seperate variables?
Thanks!

Comment: Look into `argv` and `sscanf`.

Comment: What part of it are you having trouble with? Arguments are in `argv`, so `argv[1]` contains either `x` or `y`. Use `strcmp()` to compare with a string. Then `argv[2]` contains the number, you can use `atoi()` or `sscanf()` to convert it to an `int`.

Comment: `sscanf` would be better than `atol` as you could detect if it is not a number

Answer (score 0):

The command intput `./practice x 33` in C language can be read with `argc` and `argv`.

You put it like this:

```c
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

`Argc` corresponds to the number os arguments that you've introduced (`./practice x 33` -> 3 arguments).
`Argv` corresponds to the actual string in those arguments (`argv[0]` is equal to `./practice`; `argv[1]` is equal to `x` and  `argv[2]` is equal to `33`).

So in your program you can make an argument limiter so that the program doesn't run with more than 3 arguments:

```c
if(argc != 3){
    printf("Input Error!\n")
    return 1;
}
```

Then you can make more limiters so the user only can introduce `x` and `y` letters for the `argv[1]` (etc.).

For the `argv[2]` wich is your number input, you'll need to convert it to `int type`, because, as I said before, `argv` stores `string type`.
The easiest way to do this is using `sscanf()` function. So you can make:

```c
int number;
sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &number);
```

Comment: ... and c heck the return value from `sscanf`

Comment: @EdHeal you mean to verify if there is any number in `argv[2]`?